# Background image to Tiles

Tags: libgdx, game-development, tiled

I'm using tiled map editor and libgdx to create a game, I have a vector based image that was included in the package I bought for my sprites, when I use the image in tiledmap editor the game does not run so I thought that the best think to do was to create a tile set based off my image, which I did in Photoshop, I used the slice tool saved it for web as png and ended up with 890 tiles each one 168 by 168 but when I put even 1 single tile of my new set in my game it does not run and when I take it off it does run.

How do I convert my image in a tile set which can be used in tiled map editor to be used with libgdx?

Comment: Show us the code you are using to put each image into a tile. Also what error message do you get when you try to run the game when using the tiles?

Comment: Usualy Tiled does this for you. You add one big Image and set the height/width for each tile and that's it. Maybe it's some unsupported Image format?